# Get listitem from listBox - zk

Tags: mvvm, zk

My problem : I want to get the listitem of the button so I can apply style to it in a MVVM zk.

Currently I have this :

```
    <listbox id="listbox" model="@bind(vm.myList) @template('items')">
     <listhead>
        <listheader hflex="3"label="Client" align="left" />
        <listheader hflex="3"label="show" align="left" />
     </listhead>
     <template name="items" var="item">
            <listitem   value="@bind(item.client)" />
            <listitem>
               <button hflex="1" label="show"                                                       
                 onClick="@command('ShowClient')" />
            </listitem>
    </template>
    </listbox>
```

So when I click on the button show, A popup will appear and I want to apply a style to the line of the client where the button was clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

There are some way's you can handle this.
You can use in your VM the following :

```
@Command
public void showClient (@ContextParam(ContextType.COMPONENT) Button button) {
    button.setStyle("");
}
```

Now, take care here. if your event is triggered from a component what is NOT a `Button`, you will have a `ClassCastException`.
So when this happens, just reduce `Button` to `Component` and cast it to `Button` when it's a `Button`.
You could also use the class : `HtmlBasedComponent`. 
Like this you have the lowest class what supports `setStyle` and you never need to cast it then. 
Most components inherits from this class, so lesser chance of a `ClassCastException`.